# Passing float value from ViewController to some Class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I'm new to objective-c programming and I stuck.
I have uislider in my viewcontroller and float variable in header file of viewcontroller.
I also have a new class which changes look of my second view, I overwritten drawRect.

I simply take value of slider.value and save it in my float variable then I try to access float variable in my class because this variable defines width of lines which i want to draw.

header file of my view controller

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController 
{
float lineWidth;
}

@property float lineWidth;
-(float)changingline;
@end
```

viecontroller.m  //sliderForLine = UISlider

```
- (IBAction)valuechangedForLine:(UISlider *)sender 
{

float sliderValue = sliderForLine.value;
lineWidth = sliderValue;
[self changingline];

}
-(float)changingline
{   
NSLog(@"%f", lineWidth);

return lineWidth;
}
```

NSLog says there is some value in lineWidth

class which specifies how the second UIView should looks like

```
#import "ViewController.h"

ViewController *oldView = [[ViewController alloc] init];
CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, oldView.lineWidth);
NSLog(@"%f",oldView.lineWidth);
```

and here, in second class, NSLog says always 0.

I'm confused, I don't even know now why I'm using -(void)changeling :)

All I know is that I'm missing the main point how to pass values between classes, can somebody explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance :]

Comment: Could you please be more specific on how you pass the float value from one class to another. I can't seem to understand your setup.

Comment: You are creating a completely new `ViewController` object so the float value has never been set for that instance. You need to hold a reference to your existing view controller OR create a protocol and respective methods to pass the value to a delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You NEED (not want) a delegate for this.  Try something like this:

header file of my view controller

```
@protocol ViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

@required

-(void)valueChanged:(float)value;

@end

@interface ViewController : UIViewController 
{
float lineWidth;
id<ViewControllerDelegate> _delegate;
}

@property float lineWidth;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<ViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
-(float)changingline;
@end
```

//.m

```
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
...

- (IBAction)valuechangedForLine:(UISlider *)sender 
{

float sliderValue = sliderForLine.value;
lineWidth = sliderValue;
[self.delegate valueChanged:lineWidth];

}
```

Then all you need to do is conform to the protocol with a pair of these <> and implement the required method.

Also, rename your iVar with an underscore (so, instead of `lineWidth`, use `_lineWidth`) then `@synthesize lineWidth = _lineWidth`

Comment: `//.h
#import "firstViewController.h"

@interface SecondView : UIView <ViewControllerDelegate>
{
    float line;
    
}
@property float line;

//.m

#import "firstViewController.h"
@synthesize line;

-(void)valueChanged:(float)value
{
    line = value;
}
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{ 
 CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, line);
   NSLog(@"%f",line);
}`
nslog says 0, I changed my firstViewController as you suggested but still seems like it doesn't work. Why should I use underscore for my iVars? I didn't reply because I had to find out what protocol is as I'm beginning with objective-c.

Comment: Add in [view setNeedsDisplay]; in your valuechanged method.

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you describe a class `ViewController` that subclasses UIViewController. You show the interface (.h) and you show two methods from the implementation (.m). You show code where a new object of the class (oldView) is allocated and initialized. However, you do not show how the a new class object is initialized (you do not show its init method).

`lineWidth` is a property of the the object oldView, and you refer to it immediately after you initialize oldView in  these lines:

```
ViewController *oldView = [[ViewController alloc] init]; 
CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, oldView.lineWidth); 
NSLog(@"%f",oldView.lineWidth);
```

Yet, nowhere do you show where the value of lineWidth is initialized. Maybe you didn't initialize it. Maybe `- (IBAction)valuechangedForLine:(UISlider *)sender`  didn't get called. Could that be your problem?